# Azure B2C and authentication with token

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm creating some webapi in `.NET Core` with `C#`. I'm using `Azure B2C` as `identity manager`. When a user does the login, its application receives a `token`: I think it is a `JWT`.

How can I validate the token from my webapi against `Azure B2C`? Can I refresh automatically this token before the expired date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be what you are looking for?: [An ASP.NET Core 2.0 web API with Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/)

Basically you handle validation in ASP.NET Core with the JWT Bearer middleware:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  { 
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
  {
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
      OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
  });
```

...and validates scopres like this:

```
var scopes = HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope")?.Value;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TheScope) && scopes != null && scopes.Split(' ').Any(s => s.Equals(TheScope)))
      // Do stuff
  else 
      // Unauthorized
```